# Using a 2-3-4 tree instead of a splay tree

Tags: data-structures, splay-tree, 2-3-4-tree

I'm in a data structures course right now and we learned about 2-3-4 trees and splay trees.  I was wondering in what circumstances would you use a 2-3-4 tree instead of a splay tree?  They're both self balancing and sorted so I don't see that much of a difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [2-3-4 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree) only changes the structure on insertions and deletions, while a [splay-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) also re-organizes the nodes on searches.

Splay trees will, thanks to the re-organization on lookup, provide faster responses if your typical usage pattern happens to look up a small subset of elements most of the time.

It is possible to implement a 2-3-4 tree such that the smallest element can be looked up in O(1), but generally both offer insertion and deletion at amortized O(log n).